# How to express constraints on consecutive relations of the Neo4j shortestpath query algoritm?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I would like to query a shortestpath in Neo4j but expressing conditions between consecutive relations.

Suppose I have nodes labelled `type` and relations labelled `rel`. Such relations have the attributes `start_time`, `end_time`, `exec_time` (for the moment they are of type string, but if you prefer you can consider them as integer). I would like to find the shortest path between two nodes `b1` and `b2` subject to the constraint that:

- the relation outgoing from `b1` should have the attribute `starting_time` bigger than a given value (let me call it `th`;
- if there are more than one of such relations, `starting_time` of the next relation should be bigger than `ending_time` of the previous.

Between two nodes I can have multiple realations.

I started from this query limiting the relations with `starting_time` bigger than `th`.

```
MATCH (b1:type{id:"0247"}), (b2:type{id:"0222"}), 
p=shortestPath((b1)−[t:rel*]−>(b2))
WHERE ALL (r in relationships(p) WHERE r.starting_time>"14:56:00" )
RETURN p;
```

I was trying something like this:

```
MATCH (b1:type{id:"0247"}), (b2:type{id:"0222"}), 
p=shortestPath((b1)−[t:rel*]−>(b2))
WITH "14:56:00" as th
WHERE ALL (r in relationships(p) WHERE r.starting_tme>th WITH r.end_time as th )
RETURN p;
```

but it does not work and I am not sure the `shortestPath` algorithm in Neo4j accesses the relations of the shortest path sequentially.

How can I express such a condition in Neo4j cypher query language?

If it is not possible is there a suitable way to model such a time condition in a graph database (I mean how can I change the DB?)

Answer (score 1):

This query may do what you want:

```
MATCH p = shortestPath((b1:type{id:"0247"})−[t:rel*]−>(b2:type{id:"0222"}))
WHERE REDUCE(s = {ok: true, last: "14:56:00"}, r IN RELATIONSHIPS(p) |
  {ok: s.ok AND r.starting_time > s.last, last: r.end_time}
  ).ok
RETURN p;
```

This query uses [REDUCE](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/3.5/functions/list/#functions-reduce) to iteratively test the relationships while updating the current state `s` at every step.

Comment: Seems to take a lot of time.

Comment: Unbounded variable length relationship patterns are generally expensive and can lead to very long run times or even run out of memory. You may want to use a reasonable upper bound, like `[t:rel*..6]`.

Comment: Thanks for your help I will try that.